DF Player Mini Not Playing All Audio Files
I am currently using a DF Player Mini as a standalone MP3 player. However, I am facing an issue where the module goes into standby mode after playing one track and I am unable to make it play all the audio files at once. Could someone please help me with this problem?

That's not an electrical engineering issue, that's how to use the module you bought. What help do you need with it, do you have some MCU controlling it?

no i am not using a MCU

Have you tried the DFRobot Forum?

The manual says the module plays a single file and goes to wait further actions.
So, it can't function as a standalone player.
It needs a MCU to poll status and go play next song when it has finished playing one song.
